# How secure this signature based authentication for mobile devices is

Tags: wcf, security, rest, service

I am implementing an app where I don't have a system requiring username and password. What I do require is a name and a phone number.

The scenario is like this:

1) user opens the app for the first time

2)app makes a request to my server and gets a unique UserKey

3)from now one any request the app makes to my REST service also has a signature. The signature is actually a SHA(UserKey:the data provided in the request Base64Encoded)

4)The server also performs the same hash to check the signature

Why I don't use SSH:

- not willing to pay for the certificate
- I don't need to send sensitive data like passwords, so I don't see the benefit of using it
- I just need a simple way to call my own WCF REST services from own app

I understand that there is a flow of security at step2 when the UserKey comes in cleartext, but this happens only once when the app is first opened. How dangerous do you think this is?

What would you recommend? Is there any .NET library that could help me?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there are several problems with that approach. Suppose there's man-in-the-middle whenever you make a request to the server. By analyzing, for example, 100 sent packets he would recognize similar pattern with signature in your requests. Then he would forge his own request and add your signature. The server checks the hash - everything's alright, it's you and your unique user key. But it's not.

There's a notion of asymmetric keys in cryptography which currently is really popular and provides tough security service. Main concept is the following: server generates two keys - public and private; public key is used to encode texts; they can be decoded only with the use of private key, which is kept by the server in secure location. So server gives client the public key to encode his messages. It may be made double: client generates public key and gives it to the server. Then server generates keys and gives encoded with client's public key his own public key. This way it's almost impossible for man-in-the-middle to make an attack.

Better yet, since the problem is really common, you could use OAuth to authorize users on your website. It is secure, widely used (facebook, g+, twitter, you name them) and has implementations already in variety of languages.

Answer (score 1):

Since you control both the application itself and the webservices, you can do this with SSL (which gets rid of the problems with your current approach) without paying for anything. You can create a self-signed certificate and install that on your webserver; configure the SSL context of your client application to only trust that one certificate. Then, create a client-side self-signed certificate and install that within your application. Set the server up to require mutually-authenticated SSL and only allow your self-signed certificate for access.

Done. You client will only talk to your legitimate server (so no one can spoof your server and trick the client in to talking to it) and your server will only talk to your legitimate clients (so no one can steal information, ID, etc). And it's all protected with the strong cryptography used within SSL.